# Purchasing PSVITA game / and its digital counterpart

Tags: psn, ps-vita

I purchased *Uncharted* and *Rayman* as my first two games for the Vita.
Already I find it annoying to have to keep going back to my bag to get the game I want to play, whereas if I just installed it or digitally downloaded it to the memory card, I could just launch it. (Lazy, I know. lol)

My question is, if I buy a physical game, can I download it free from the PSN store, or is there a way to install it on the system itself from the PSV cartridge?
I wouldn't mind trying it myself, but I don't want to make a mistake and buy it a second time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, possession of the retail copy does not automatically grant you access to its PSN digital version.

Currently, none of the retail PS Vita games are known to be installable and played directly and solely from system's internal memory or memory card (although many games require the presence of memory card for storing game-related content and save data).

Comment: Well i mean, when i visit the PSN store on Vita, i see that uncharted and rayman are both there (for 5 dollars less) than physical instore price. but i dont wanna click cause i dont wanna pay double lol...there has to be a way

Comment: It would be great to have PSN work in a similar way as Steam, so every retail copy would be redeemable on digital distribution service, allowing for redownload, updates, achievements etc. However, I believe it is not yet the case with PSN - maybe in future, it would be great, but currently no, it's not possible.

Comment: Just bear in mind buying digital versions of games has its trade-offs - there is no way to sell it and get your money back in case of blunder. You also depend on the connection to PSN, so you might not be able to access the download/installation functionality of games if PSN is down. You can get more insight on several sites, for example here: http://www.pspmod.com/forums/ps-vita-discussion/74073-should-you-go-digital-retail-ps-vita.html

Comment: thanks for the link, and i agree a STEAM like functionality would do the Vita a great service.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately a Steam-like feature doesn't mesh well with Sony's desperate scraping for cash these days.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is currently no way this is possible. At least in a legitimate method.

For perspective, there has not been a way to 'activate' your Blu-ray based PS3 games, or PSP games; as of yet. I doubt we'll see this for the Vita anytime soon.